# Buy NFT from wallet1 which has all minted nft to the user wallet connected with phantom, Javascript, Solana

Tags: cryptography, wallet, solana, nft

Here is my code to transfer nft from Alice Account (which has my all minted nfts) and feePayer account which will buy from the Alice Wallet. Well this works perfectly fine like this. But the problem is when the same transection I try to sign and send with phantom wallet it gives me an error (You can check it by the commented line 101 to 108) when I uncomment the phantom signAndSend method code and try to execute it, it gives me error RPC req rejected but the same is successfully done with the connection.sendTransaction.

That was problem 1,
Now problem 2 is that
In this case, I had used feePayer which had the keypair already, but if I want to make it as user connects with connectWallet button, ill had only publicKey of the user. Now in that situaion how can i make the the nft transfer from Alice wallet to the user who connected and clicked on buy?

JS Code:

```
const sendNft = async () => {

const feePayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode(
    "3DdVyZuANr5en2PQymCPmoFBMsfdhjaRHqnk3ejW*************************************************"
  )
);

// G2FAbFQPFa5qKXCetoFZQEvF9BVvCKbvUZvodpVidnoY
const alice = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode(
    "2YQDdnfxiHPKu9GypLX1yXaQTQojvDSPgFkDxrU*************************************************"
  )
);

const mintPubkey = new PublicKey(
  "A8SJfwzKJAaMrY6Lb9FxZCfmVMVLcjKvRuzAiNiU6of5"
);

const getProvider = async () => {
  if ("solana" in window) {

    // opens wallet to connect to
    await window.solana.connect(); 

    const provider = window.solana;
    if (provider.isPhantom) {
      console.log("Is Phantom installed?  ", provider.isPhantom);
      return provider;
    }
  } else {
    window.open("https://www.phantom.app/", "_blank");
  }
};

window.solana.on("connect", () => console.log("connected!"))

const network = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(network);

var prodivder = await getProvider();
console.log(prodivder.publicKey.toString())

var provider = await getProvider()
console.log(provider)

// calculate ATA
let accountAlice = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  mintPubkey, // mint
  alice.publicKey // owner
);
console.log(`ATA: ${accountAlice.toBase58()}`);

let tx3 = new Transaction().add(
  Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    mintPubkey, // mint
    accountAlice, // ata
    alice.publicKey, // owner of token account
    alice.publicKey // fee payer
  )
);

// calculate ATA
let accountPayer = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  mintPubkey, // mint
  feePayer.publicKey // owner
);
console.log(`ATA: ${accountPayer.toBase58()}`);

let tx2 = new Transaction().add(
  Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    mintPubkey, // mint
    accountPayer, // ata
    feePayer.publicKey, // owner of token account
    feePayer.publicKey // fee payer
  )
);
//  console.log(`txhash: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx2, [feePayer])}`);

let tx = new Transaction().add(
  Token.createTransferCheckedInstruction(
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    accountAlice, // from (should be a token account)
    mintPubkey, // mint
    accountPayer, // to (should be a token account)
    alice.publicKey, // owner of from
    [], // for multisig account, leave empty.
    1, // amount, if your deciamls is 8, send 10^8 for 1 token
    0 // decimals
  )
);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Commenting out this, thus is the phantom codes
tx2.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;
tx2.feePayer = feePayer.publicKey;
const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(tx2);
await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
// phantom code ends

  console.log(`txhash: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [feePayer, alice /* fee payer + owner */])}`);
};
```